# Own Proof environment

Tags: fonts

There are a lot of topics about the custom proof environments. But none of them do what I want to do. So let's get started:

I want to redefine! the proof environment. So i want the same behaviour as the latex proof environment. But i want to change the font and the qed symbol. So it should be something like this:

**Code**

```
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bfseries \ttfamily \scshape MyProof:}}{\ttfamily \scshape{qed}}
```

But as i said. That's not exactly what I want because there is no new line before and after the proof environment and the qed is not on right side of the last line of the proof and so on.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the right hooks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\proofname}{\normalfont\ttfamily\scshape MyProof:}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\texttt{QED}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Very easy exercise for the reader.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Then, after seeing the result, decide for not doing it. `;-)`

### With `babel`

If you are using `babel`, remember that `\proofname` is one of the language specific tags, so its redefinition must be done via the language caption mechanism:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\proofname}{\normalfont\ttfamily\scshape MyProof:}%
}
```

Use the appropriate `\captions<language>` command.

Comment: Using the optional argument for `proof` will not automatically preserve the font change unless manually incorporated.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, you're right. I don't think it's needed anyway.

Comment: I agree; I just thought it's worth mentioning (the need to introduce the font change manually), in case OP decides to use the optional argument.

Comment: @egreg It's weird. In your / my minimal example the changes of the proof environment do work. In my actual document it doesn't. Nothing changed although I have copied the two changes into preamble (before \begin{document}). Do have any ideas why it doesn't work there?

Comment: @Tech Sorry, no. What do you mean by “doesn't work”?

Comment: @egreg The proof environment haven't changed at all.

Comment: @Tech Are you loading `babel`?

Comment: @egreg Yes, I am. How am I able to redefine the proof environment anyhow?

Comment: @Tech I added the workaround

Comment: @egreg Sorry, but the "qed symbol" doesn't show up. Do you know why? Before I have changed it, there wasn't one either by the way.

Comment: @Tech Not without an example of code that “doesn't work”.

Comment: @egreg I narrowed it down. It seems that this \usepackage[amsmath,hyperref,thmmarks]{ntheorem} overwrites the qed symbol or something. When this line is in the preamble then the qed symbol doesn't show up.

Comment: @Tech Usage of `ntheorem` was ***very*** important information. In my opinion you should use `amsthm`, instead. But if you want to stick with `ntheorem`, I believe the right command is `\qedsymbol{\texttt{QED}}`, rather than `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\texttt{QED}}`

Comment: @egregThank you very much. It works finally.